# Nuget package sources: global nuget.config for VS2019?

Tags: github, nuget, visual-studio-2019

My organization is just getting started with using github, and we're trying to convert our internally developed dependencies into Github nuget packages from private repos.  I first attempted to add our package feed into package sources using **Tools | Options | NuGet Package Manager | Package Sources**.  However I didn't see anywhere to put in credentials, so as I expected, I got nothing but 401's from the Nuget UI.

My next attempt was creating a nuget.config file within my project, as per https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages.  THAT worked like a charm.

However, my aim here is to set up a global package source, for any solution I create, to access these internal dependencies without needing to add that config file to every new project.

So... is there a global nuget.config, or similar that visual studio uses for the nuget UI, that where I can append my private package source?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Visual Studio has a global `nuget.config` file exists in `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`(C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config). You should config into it and then all the solutions can use it directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So... is there a global nuget.config, or similar that visual studio
>   uses for the nuget UI, that where I can append my private package
>   source?

Visual Studio has a global `nuget.config` file exits under `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` and in my side, it is `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`.

Then you can set your settings in this file and can be used directly in a project.

You can check [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

[image]

**Note that**: it can be overridden by the `nuget.config` file in your project.